# unable to get right json format when I convert an object twice using gson

Tags: java, android, json, kotlin, gson

I have a class `OfflineDataRequestInfo` in which some of the field data is already in json format and some are not in json format. and when I try to convert the whole object `OfflineDataRequestInfo` to json it adds `\` to the fields which are already in json format.

I am using GSON.

```
data class OfflineDataRequestInfo (
    @Expose val status: String,
    @Expose val userId: String?,
    @Expose val fulOrderId: String,
    @Expose val timestamp: String,
    @Expose val vehicle: String,
    @Expose val fulOrder: String,
    @Expose val checks: String?
)
```

this is my data which is in the object. and I want to convert into json

```
OfflineDataRequestInfo(status=check, userId=null, fulOrderId=5f87220aeeec51376a1a95b5, timestamp=null, vehicle=5d4c0ffe3a7e5800da370b22, fulOrder={"status":"check"})
```

when I do gson.toJson on above value

```
gson.toJson(requestInfoJson)
```

I get

```
{"fulOrder":"{\"status\":\"check\"}","fulOrderId":"5f87220aeeec51376a1a95b5","vehicle":"5d4c0ffe3a7e5800da370b22"}
```

how can I fix this please

Comment: that's because when you convert it into object this `{"status":"check"}` is treated as a whole string and when you convert it back, since json already saving key and value inside double quote, it appends \ before double quote so as to ignore it while parsing.

Comment: how can i fix this

Comment: you'd need to treat `fulOrder` as an object first, by deserialising your `{"status": "check"}` JSON into an object first, then by serialising the full `OfflineDataRequestInfo` object into a string